# How can do increments&decrements for a character? (Java)

Tags: java

**Requirement:**

How can I print ..

- one previous character (e.g. *a*),
- the entered character and (e.g. *b*)
- the next character? (e.g. *c*)

When I enter *b*, the output should be *a b c*.

**This is what I tried** *- unfortunately it does not work:*

```
import java.util.*;

public class stackoverflow { 
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char a;
        System.out.println("I have problems in printing statement");
        a = sc.nextcharAt(0);
        System.out.println((a-1)+""+a+""+(a+1));
    }
}
```

I hope the main problem is in the printing statement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can increment a `char ch` with `ch++;` and decrement `ch--` just like any other integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast to char type

```
System.out.println((char) (a - 1) + " " + a + " " + (char) (a + 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
 public class stackoverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char a;
        System.out.println("I have problems in printing statement");
        a = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println((char)(a - 1) + "" + a + "" + (char)(a + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your scanner command a little and have proper typecasting

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a letter: ");
int a = (int)sc.next().charAt(0);
System.out.printf("%c %c %c\n", (a-1), a, (a+1));
```

Below is a variant that loops until the user enters a 0 (zero)

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a letter (exit with 0): ");
    int a = (int)sc.next().charAt(0);
    if ((char)a == '0') 
        break;
    System.out.printf("%c %c %c\n", (a-1), a, (a+1));
}
```